# How to make a login form where the password is the reversed form of the typed in username input

Tags: javascript

I need to make a login form where you can "login" with any username as long as the password is reversed form of the username

I have tried the split(""), reverse(), and join("") method but it does not seem to be working.

```
//HTML
    <form>
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
      <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </form>
```

```
//Javascript
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

reverseInput = stringReverse(username);

function login() {
  if (password === reverseInput) {
    alert("Authorized");
  } else {
    alert("Unauthorized");
  }
}
```

I expect the output to popup with the alert "Authorized" when the typed in password is the reversed form of the username input.

Comment: That's not what palindrome means.

Comment: because value is read on page load.... that does not magically update as user enters text,,.,, simple console.log  will show you these things

Answer (score 0):

As you declare `var username value` outside function value of username and password never update

```
 <form>
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
      <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function stringReverse(string) {
           return string.split("").reverse().join("");
        }


        function login() {
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
          if (password === reverseInput) {
            alert("Authorized");
          } else {
            alert("Unauthorized");
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the variables when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks the login button.

Also, you need to prevent the button from submitting the form, by using `type="button"`.

```js
function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
  if (password === reverseInput) {
    alert("Authorized");
  } else {
    alert("Unauthorized");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <label>Password: </label>
  <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are running into is that all of following is running before the user has a chance to fill it out.

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
```

You want to move all of that into the login function.

```
function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
  if (password === reverseInput) {
    alert("Authorized");
  } else {
    alert("Unauthorized");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are outside the login method and they are apparently global variables within your script.
For this reason it will always have the value that input username has at the time of loading the screen.

For this code to work you must either include the variable within the login method:

```js
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
    if (password === reverseInput) {
      alert("Authorized");
    } else {
      alert("Unauthorized");
    }
}

function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <label>Password: </label>
  <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

Or update it with each change in the username text field. So you need to add onchange event or events. But it's not ideal because you would be doing some extra work:

```js
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

function stringReverse(string) {
  return string
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

reverseInput = stringReverse(username);

function login() {
  if (password === reverseInput) {
    alert("Authorized");
  } else {
    alert("Unauthorized");
  }
}

function updateUserNameVariable() {
    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
}

function updatePasswordAndReverse() {
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    reverseInput = stringReverse(username);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" onchange="updateUserNameVariable()" />
  <label>Password: </label>
  <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" onchange="updatePasswordAndReverse()" />
  <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

As Barmar said you also need to change your button type to "button". A button inside a form will by default be type "submit", with that your form will be submited automatically before your validation. So you add the `type='button'` in the button tag will prevent the form to be submitted automatically. Then you can call the form submit method after the validation like that `document.getElementByTagName('form').submit();`